# MongoDb - Search documents in 2 collections with same text search on there names

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection by name businesses. Document in business looks like below

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "60a34c76d8b10300111325ea"
  },
  "services": [
    {
      "$oid": "60a34da258d8b50011859c4d"
    },
    {
      "$oid": "60a34dc7d8b10300111325f7"
    }
  ],
  "description": "Dev",
  "businessName": "Amul Milk Center",
  "businessId": "VD627523"
}]
```

We have 3 services of the business as below in the services collection. The service collection document looks like below

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "60a34da258d8b50011859c4d"
  },
  "service": "Amul Milk Cow",
  "businessId": {
    "$oid": "60a34c76d8b10300111325ea"
  }
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "60a34dc7d8b10300111325f7"
  },
  "service": "Amul Milk Buffalo",
  "businessId": {
    "$oid": "60a34c76d8b10300111325ea"
  }
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "620ea45b9a94ea160049cfc5"
  },
  "service": "Amul Ice Cream",
  "businessId": {
    "$oid": "60a34c76d8b10300111325ea"
  }
}]
```

If I search “Amul Milk” then I should get “businessName”: “Amul Milk Center” from the business collection and the 2 services of the business named as “service”: “Amul Milk Buffalo” & “service”: “Amul Milk Cow” from the services collection.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the exact output desired, but here's one way to do it.

```js
db.service.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "service": {
        "$regex": "Amul Milk"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "business",
      "localField": "businessId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "businessName"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "service": 1,
      "businessName": {
        "$first": "$businessName.businessName"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

And here's the output you get.

```js
[
  {
    "businessName": "Amul Milk Center",
    "service": "Amul Milk Cow"
  },
  {
    "businessName": "Amul Milk Center",
    "service": "Amul Milk Buffalo"
  }
]
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HU_GV-1bjuY).